# Vaadin mapping not working with MicroProfile Rest Client

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, wildfly-swarm, microprofile

I'm building a Vaadin 8 + Wildfly Swarm example.

In my first step, I had built an example of multi-module of a Vaadin Application, according to [Data-Centric Applications with Vaadin 8](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/data-centric-applications-with/9781783288847/).

Then as a second step, I was testing some Vaadin APIs, when I added the **Wildfly Swarm Microprofile Rest Client**. I know that this module has [some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50955247/microprofile-rest-client-not-working), but when I added it in a **Vaadin** + **Wildfly Swarm** application, I lose the Vaadin Mapping and I cannot reach my frontend application!

My first example is working on the [master branch of this repository](https://github.com/vepo/vaadin-example). And this is the Wildfly Swarm fractions loaded without  Microprofile Rest Client:

```
2018-06-21 10:30:06,106 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                  Logging - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:logging:2018.3.3
2018-06-21 10:30:06,116 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:          Bean Validation - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:bean-validation:2018.3.3
2018-06-21 10:30:06,116 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:        CDI Configuration - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:cdi-config:2018.3.3
2018-06-21 10:30:06,117 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:             Transactions - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:transactions:2018.3.3
2018-06-21 10:30:06,117 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                      CDI - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:cdi:2018.3.3
2018-06-21 10:30:06,117 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                 Undertow - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:undertow:2018.3.3
```

My second step can be found in [this branch](https://github.com/vepo/vaadin-example/tree/rest-client). And this is the Wildfly Swarm fractions loaded with Microprofile Rest Client:

```
2018-06-21 10:34:01,885 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                  Logging - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:logging:2018.3.3
2018-06-21 10:34:01,893 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:          Bean Validation - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:bean-validation:2018.3.3
2018-06-21 10:34:01,894 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:        CDI Configuration - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:cdi-config:2018.3.3
2018-06-21 10:34:01,894 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                  Elytron - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:elytron:2018.3.3
2018-06-21 10:34:01,894 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                      CDI - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:cdi:2018.3.3
2018-06-21 10:34:01,895 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:       JAX-RS with JSON-P - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:jaxrs-jsonp:2018.3.3
2018-06-21 10:34:01,895 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                   JAX-RS - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:jaxrs:2018.3.3
2018-06-21 10:34:01,896 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction: Eclipse MicroProfile Config - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:microprofile-config:2018.3.3
2018-06-21 10:34:01,896 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction: Microprofile Rest Client - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:microprofile-restclient:2018.3.3
2018-06-21 10:34:01,896 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:             Transactions - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:transactions:2018.3.3
2018-06-21 10:34:01,896 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                 Undertow - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:undertow:2018.3.3
```

How can I make all work together?